# c++11 library for indigo catkin package

Tags: ros, ros-indigo, c++11

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a library (a server using std::thread and some other c++11 things like auto) which is compiled into mylib.a.

I want to use this library in my indigo catkin ros node. But apparently ROS is c++03 only for now.

Do I have to rewrite the library to c++03? Or can I use it as long as the ros node itself stays c++03 compatible?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190308/c++11-library-for-indigo-catkin-package/) by [matheusz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19018/matheusz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2014-08-15

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-08-15**:
As far as I know they are not ABI compatible.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-08-15**:
My experience has been that basic things like the std::vector and std::string are not ABI-compatible between c++03 and c++11, so mixing code compiled by different c++ versions is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting weird linker errors when testing to build a simple catkin package with this library and c++11 enabled in the compiler. So it won't work then. Thanks for the responses.

---

Originally posted by [matheusz](https://answers.ros.org/users/19018/matheusz/) with karma: 90 on 2014-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1